# XSLT group parts of a list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm struggling to convert parts of a list into a group.

Say I have a list like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Three</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Four</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Five</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and want to transform this to

```
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<div class="group">
    <a href="#">Three</a>
    <a href="#">Four</a>
    <a href="#">Five</a>
</div>
<p>Six</p>
```

I have no clue how to realize this. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
It would be helpful to have something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="td[a and ( preceding-sibling::td/a or following-sibling::td/a )]">
    <div class="group"> <!-- this has to be called one time !! -->
        <xsl:for-each select=".//a">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

My approach was that the brackets should group all matches to one execution of the template, so that only one grouping div is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation** (without any `xsl:apply-templates` instruction):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="tr/td/text()">
     <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tr[td[a]][1]">
  <div class="group">
   <xsl:copy-of select="../tr[td[a]]/td/a"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Three</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Four</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Five</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<div class="group">
   <a href="#">Three</a>
   <a href="#">Four</a>
   <a href="#">Five</a>
</div>
<p>Six</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the goal with something like this

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//tr/td"/>
        <div class="group">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//td/a"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//tr/td"> 
        <p><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//td/a"> 
        <a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></a>
    </xsl:template>
```

Edit : the code parser drop an important peace of code :/ it's now ok

Hope this could help

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately `<xsl:apply-templates select="//tr/td"/>` will call those `td`s with `a`s inside, too, which is not helpful. Besides apply-templates will be very expensive to implement in this system :-/

Comment: yes it's true, I've just tried to show a way to 'almost' reach the goal. may be with a if to filter the 'a'

Comment: You can select only the `td` elements that have no `a` children with `<xsl:apply-templates select="//tr/td[not(a)]"/>`

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned implementing the apply-templates will be harder to realize. I can't believe there is no solution with template match="..."

Comment: I found the same as Ian Roberts just right now :) I continue to dig if we could do with template match

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
 <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/tr[not(td/a) or not(preceding-sibling::tr/td/a)]" />
 </root>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr[not(td/a)]" priority="0.6">
 <p>
   <xsl:copy-of select="td/@* | td/node()" /> 
 </p>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr[td]">
 <div class="group">
   <xsl:copy-of select="
    td/@* | td/node() | 
    following-sibling::tr[
        preceding-sibling::tr[not(preceding-sibling::tr/td/a)][1]
     ]/td/node()" /> 
 </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will transform your sample input into ...

```
<root>
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <div class="group">
    <a href="#">Three</a>
    <a href="#">Four</a>
    <a href="#">Five</a>
  </div>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sean. That is one complex transformation... I improved my example template based on your selectors to show what exactly I need. Because I just provided some example input XML I can't apply your suggested transformation to my original XML - it is way more complex and wouldn't work. Is it really so hard to gather all connected `td/a`s, wrap them with one node-set and leave all other `td`s untouched?

Comment: No it's not hard. The main problem is just to articulate the rules of transformation. If you can be unambiguous, cover edge cases and supply use cases, any problem can be solved. XSLT does grouping well. Search on StackOverflow and Google for Muenchian grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found a solution myself, that suits my needs:

```
<xsl:template match="tr[td/a and following-sibling::tr/td/a][1]">
    <div class="list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//a | following-sibling::tr//a"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="td[p/a]"/>
```

Thanks for your help guys.